# How to resolve the same conflict in all the files

Tags: java, git, github

I merged changes from another repo to my repo and resulted in one conflict that is a copyright comment in all Java classes:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
 * Copyright (C) 2010-2017 Peter, Sofi, and Others
=======
 * Copyright (C) 2010-2018 Peter, Sofi, and Others
>>>>>>> 01e35t13155963q84e8e05b7101235488c50f4e639eew3c4
```

The conflict is trivial and easy to solve but the issue is that this conflict appears on more than 50 Java classes which I think is difficult to go through all of them and resolve the conflict manually.

Is there a quick way to resolve this conflict in all the classes automatically? BTW, I use Eclipse.

Comment: You can use plugin Git on Eclipse, select all file and fix on one time all conflicts [check how to do that](https://wiki.52north.org/Documentation/ResolveMergeConflictsInGitEclipse)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `git rerere`

To enable rerere functionality, you simply have to run this config setting:

```
$ git config --global rerere.enabled true
```

[image]

When we merge the two branches together, we’ll get a merge conflict:

```
$ git merge i18n-world
Auto-merging hello.rb
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in hello.rb
Recorded preimage for 'hello.rb'
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

Now you can resolve it to just be puts 'hola mundo' and you can run git rerere diff again to see what rerere will remember:

```
$ git rerere diff
--- a/hello.rb
+++ b/hello.rb
@@ -1,11 +1,7 @@
 #! /usr/bin/env ruby

 def hello
-<<<<<<<
-  puts 'hello mundo'
-=======
-  puts 'hola world'
->>>>>>>
+  puts 'hola mundo'
 end
```

So that basically says, when Git sees a hunk conflict in a hello.rb file that has “hello mundo” on one side and “hola world” on the other, it will resolve it to “hola mundo”.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is `git rerere`. This will save conflict resolutions for you. You can find some extra information [here in this doc entry](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rerere). This will reuse the conflict resolution provided the next one will be identical.